# How to parse JSON in Swift 2.1?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift2

I need to parse a JSON String like this

```
{
    "someData": [{
        "title": "Test!",
        "content": "hello!"
    }, {
        "title": "Test 2!",
        "content": "hello!"
    }],
    "otherData": [{
        "title": "Hey",
        "content": "yes or no"
    }]
}
```

I have some code to parse json. But this code just parse json which is only in one array. I have played with the code, so I can parse an array which is in an array which has text in it (I mean this json on the top).

Now I give up... What I have to do that this can work?

```
let jsonString = NSString(data: getJSON("URL"), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let jsonData = jsonString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    do {
        if let parsed = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:  NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? [[String : AnyObject]]) {
            for items in parsed {
                if let item = items as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let title = item["title"] as? String
                    doSomething(title!)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

Comment: you should use the SwiftyJSON form here : https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

```
   func parseJSON() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data1", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)! as NSData
    do {
        let newJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        if let otherData = newJson["otherData"] as? NSArray {
            let newData1 = otherData[0]
            if let content = newData1["content"] as? String {
                if let title = newData1["title"] as? String {
                    print(title)
                    print(content)
                }

            }
        }

        if let someData = newJson["someData"] as? NSArray {
            var x = 0
            while x < someData.count {
                if let title = someData[x]["title"] as? String {
                    if let content = someData[x]["content"] as? String {
                        print(title)
                        print(content)
                    }
                }
                x++
            }

        }


    }
    catch {

    }

}
```

then, in your viewDidLoad:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    parseJSON()
}
```

Edit:

This is assuming that you have the json file named "data1.json" and it is in your project directory like so:

[image]

If the json file does not have this name or is in another place in your project directory, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a JSON string is quite easy.

There are only two collection types:

- Dictionary (or Object in terms of the specification), represented by a pair of curly braces `{}`
- Array, represented by a pair of square brackets `[]`

All keys in JSON are of type `String` by definition therefore the least specific type of an dictionary is `[String:AnyObject]`.

---

In your example the root object is a dictionary `{}` containing two keys `someData` and `otherData` so the line to create a JSON object is supposed to be (no `if - let`)

```
let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:[]) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

`someData` contains an array of dictionaries `[{...},{...}]`, in your example all values are strings so you can constrain the object to `[[String:String]]` and parse the items with

```
if let someData = parsed["someData"] as? [[String:String]] {
  for anItem in someData {
    print(anItem["title"]!)
    print(anItem["content"]!)
  }
}
```

For simple structures a third party library like `SwiftyJSON` is actually not needed.

Comment: just a note ... "Early versions of JSON (such as specified by RFC 4627) required that a valid JSON "document" must consist of only an object or an array type—though they could contain other types within them. This restriction was removed starting with RFC 7158, so that a JSON document may consist entirely of any possible JSON typed value."